# Running lazy collection inside a Transaction Still returning LazyInitializationException

Tags: hibernate, jpa, transactions, spring-data-jpa, lazy-loading

I have integrated Spring boot with JavaFX application, 
So anotating class with @Transactional will throw NullPointerException (
Maybe there a synchronisation problem with FXMLLoader and spring boot)
Any way i have decided to create a transaction manually using EntityManager.
My entity has lazy properties, when i try to access a lazy property inside a transaction, i still getting LazyInitializationException.

Code for my entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idproduct")
    private Long idProduct;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    Set<CommercialePieceItem> commercialePieceItems = new HashSet<>();

    }
```

I have tried many approches to initialize lazy collection but no thing works

1 try :

```
 @Autowired
    EntityManagerFactory emf;


  EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager() ;
                entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
                entityManager.merge(product);
                int qty = product.getCommercialePieceItems().size() ;
                entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
                entityManager.close(); ;
```

At line

> int qty = product.getCommercialePieceItems().size() ; it throws  a 
>   LazyInitializationException

Try 2 :

```
 TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(platformTransactionManager) ; 
                transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus transactionStatus) {
                        Hibernate.initialize(product.getCommercialePieceItems());
                        return null;
                    }
                });
```

> Also it throws a LazyInitializationException ;

Try 3 : i tried to use a helper service :

```
@Service
public class DatabaseService {

 @Transactional
    public void initializeLazyObject(Object objects) {
        Hibernate.initialize(objects);


    }
}
@Autowired
DatabaseService databaseservice ; 

databaseservice.initializeLazyObject(product.getCommercialePieceItems()) ;
```

As always it throws a LazyInitializationException ;

So, what's the problem her ? 
How can i fix this LazyInitializationException  in Spring Data JPA ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you have a running transaction and therefore an active session/persistence context your entity is not attached to that persistence context.

The problem is that `merge` returns an attached instance, but you are not using that attached instance but the detached one that you started with. 
Simply replace

```
entityManager.merge(product);
```

with

```
product = entityManager.merge(product);
```

and your code should work.

Also, see https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-persist-and-merge/ and https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge-T-